# Automatic Silent backup of postgresql database running on a AWS ec2 machine through shell script?

Tags: amazon-ec2, database-backups, bash, cron-task, postgresql-9.5

I am running a postgresql database on AWS ec2 machine and scheduling the backup of the database every night at 12:00 a.m. by crontab which executes a shell script containing all the commands to backup the data. The problem is, I want to do it without stopping the database service. Please help!

Comment: what method you use? cold directory copy? I don't see why would you stop db at all..

Comment: Hi! I am using pg_dump. If I don't stop the db service,then would my database backup be successful and complete? If other users are accessing the db at same time while taking the backup, will it not conflict or create any problems with the data? Thank you !

Comment: if you do stop postgres, you won't be able to `pg_dump`

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html,

> pg_dump is a utility for backing up a PostgreSQL database. It makes
>   consistent backups even if the database is being used concurrently.
>   pg_dump does not block other users accessing the database (readers or
>   writers).

You run it without stopping the service

Comment: Okay! Thank you again :)

Comment: sure, no worries